# Using htaccess file to redirect .css and .js files while still allowing site to use them

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking for help with creating an .htaccess file that redirects all .css and .js files to my homepage, but still allows me to use them on both my site and other sites. I tried using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*\.css$ /home [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*\.js$ /home [R=301,L]
```

This successfully redirected me to my homepage, but when I tried to use the files in a project the CSS and JS didn't load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have css and js inside root directory?

Comment: If you want to keep these as external resources that are requested from the client-side page then this is not possible.

Comment: Are you sure? I think I've seen this done before.

Comment: There is no point trying to prevent access to these files. Modern browsers can inspect the elements and see the styles and js code that the browser(client) loaded. Even the largest sites out there don't bother. Some do obfuscate the JS file but trying to prevent access is not going work.